# react-map-gl - India geoLocation is showing Incorrect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

i am rendering indian cities on map using marker component of react-map-gl ,
showing ex. Mumbai "lat": "19.0760", "long": "72.8777" on react-map-gl but it is showing in incorrect position on map .

find Img link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlhqg.png

```
{
    "cities": [
      {
        "name": "Mumbai",
        "state": "Maharashtra",
        "lat": "19.0760",
        "lon": "72.8777"
      }
      
    ]
  }

// compoment

      [{cityList.cities.map(city => (
          <Marker
            key={city.name}
            latitude={parseInt(city.lat)}
            longitude={parseInt(city.lon)}
            offsetLeft={-20} offsetTop={-10}
          >
            <button
              className="marker-btn"
              onClick={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log(city.name);
              }}
            >
              {city.name}
            </button>
          </Marker>
        ))}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with parseInt

answer - https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/issues/1145